# Python shorthand for conditionally assigning a variable

Tags: python

I find myself writing stuff like this too often and it seems too wordy:

```
obj = my_dict.get('obj')
if obj:
    var = obj
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe in one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no clean way to replace this code in one line, because it conditionally binds the name `var`. In the case that `var` was already defined, this one-liner is possible:

```
var = my_dict['obj'] if 'obj' in my_dict and my_dict['obj'] else var
```

However, this is still slightly different than the original code in case `var` was not already defined: the one-liner is raising a `NameError` and the original code just continues with `var` unbound.

Note that other answers behave differently when the value exists but is falsey.

```
obj = my_dict.get('obj')
if obj:   # <-- test on truthiness of obj
    # if we are here, it means:
    #   1. my_dict has key 'obj', AND...
    #   2. at least one of the following,
    #        my_dict['obj'].__bool__() returned True (__nonzero__ for Python 2)
    #      OR
    #        my_dict['obj'].__len__() returned result > 0
    #      OR
    #        my_dict['obj'] is not None, and has neither __bool__ nor __len__ defined
    var = obj
```

Comment: Thanks for putting some thought into this. Your solution is the closest match for the exact code I wrote in my original post so I'm changing the accepted answer to yours.

Answer (score 11):

The `get` function takes a second argument, a default:

> get(key[, default])
>   Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

So, you could use the below to replicate your question's code:

```
var = my_dict.get('obj', var)
```

Comment: good, but it doesn't _exactly_ replicate the code.  for the case where `var` is not already existing in scope, your code will raise `NameError` but OP's code will continue with `var` simply remaining not in scope.

Comment: Good point, but I took the if block as being complete, in which case there would be no point assigning to the var there if it didn't already exist in scope - if there is supposed to be extra code in the if block, then sure, but I don't believe that's the case from the phrasing of the question

Comment: Still not really equivalent though.  Consider the case `my_dict = {'obj': 0}`.  Do you re-assign `var` or not?  Your code does, where the OP's would leave `var` untouched.

Comment: Ah, also a good point, my bad. I do wonder if the OP intends that behaviour though - it's a mistake I make all-too-frequently and often see others do so too...

Answer (score 2):

I find this form to be the most explicitly readable and I use it all the time:

```
moo = animals["cow"] if "cow" in animals else None
```

Comment: Good, but not equivalent.  The OP's test is on the value, not whether key is present.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `my_dict` is what it says it is (a dictionary):

`var = my_dict.get('obj') if 'obj' in my_dict else var`

Edited to preserve intent with original question.

Comment: You don't need the call to .keys() in the above snippet.  I'd shorten to: `var = my_dict['obj'] if 'obj' in my_dict else None `

Comment: That would imply that 'obj' could be either a key *or* a value, and we want only keys.  You may be right, but I feel this clarifies one's intent.

Comment: @Makoto, this is what the docs say: `key in d`: Return True if d has a key key, else False.

Comment: Just glanced over that, thanks for letting me know.  I'll update the remark shortly.

Comment: Doesn't this behave differently to the OP's example, for the case where 'obj' is a valid key, but the value is false in a boolean context? (e.g. it's an empty list or 0)

Comment: @wim, you are correct. I'm not sure what he actually wants to happen in that case though.

Comment: @Makoto I'm aware of how the ternary operator works.  my point is that for the case where `var = 'spam'`, and `my_dict = {'obj': 0}`, your code is behaving differently than the OP's example.

Comment: @vim:  Not quite.  [I ran it through](http://codepad.org/Ltc7SF3v), and it seems that, if the key exists, then the value is pushed through.  If it doesn't, then `var` is never defined.

Comment: To see what I'm talking about, notice how in your case the conditional is checking whether or not the key `'obj'` is in `my_dict`, but in the OP's case the conditional is testing whether the value `my_dict.get('obj')` is truthy or falsey.  These are not equivalent.

Comment: Try your paste instead with `var = 'spam'` and `my_dict = {'obj': 0}` and you would see the issue.

Comment: @vim:  I see what you're talking about now.  And you're right; the one liner here doesn't *convincingly* check for the key's existence before assigning it somewhere.  But ultimately, if we were looking to assign the value to `var` (which is our ultimate intent), then if the key doesn't exist, `var` is undefined.  If it does exist, then `var` has that value.  Both cases are preserved from the OP's question; if the key exists then the value is in `var`; if it doesn't, `var` doesn't exist.  This is probably where I don't see how it doesn't sync up with the OP's case.

Answer (score -1):

```
var = thedict.get('thekey', var)
```